# Show that $\sqrt{2}=\frac{5}{4}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{(4n-1)!}{(2n-1)!(2n)!2^{6n-1}}\left(1+\frac{4n+1}{8n+4}\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, number-theory

Show that

> $$\sqrt{2}=\frac{5}{4}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{(4n-1)!}{(2n-1)!(2n)!2^{6n-1}}\left(1+\frac{4n+1}{8n+4}\right)$$

The numerical value is ok , so I need the proving. Any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As with your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1203368), given the fact that $~\displaystyle\frac{(4n)!}{\Big[(2n)!\Big]^2}~=~{4n\choose2n},~$ this exercise is

obviously connected to the formula $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty{4n\choose2n}~\bigg(\frac x4\bigg)^{2n}~=~\frac12~\bigg(\frac1{\sqrt{1+x}}+\frac1{\sqrt{1-x}}\bigg),~$

which can easily be shown by expanding each term on the right into its [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).